# compiler error Error 193

Tags: windows, c

Compiler Aarch64

makefile

```
start.o: start.S
    aarch64-elf-gcc $(CFLAGS) -c start.S -o start.o
```

error output

```
aarch64-elf-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -c start.S -o start.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\rpi-eclipse\gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-i686_aarch64-elf\bin\aarch64-elf-gcc, aarch64-elf-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -c start.S -o start.o, ...) failed.
make (e=193): Error 193
make: *** [start.o] Error 193
```

Compiler errorがでます。
予想では、assennbly fileのコンパイルが64bitに対応してしていないのかと推定しています。

Comment: CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -nostartfiles

all: clean kernel8.img

start.o: start.S
 aarch64-elf-gcc $(CFLAGS)  -c start.S -o start.o

Comment: 質問文は後からでも [編集] できますので、必要であればコメント欄ではなく直接本文に情報の追記をお願いします。

Comment: 質問文がないようですが、何を訊きたいでしょうか？　メッセージの文言 `CreateProcess` に失敗している、を素直に読めばコンパイラやアセンブラが存在しない（インストールされていない）ように思えます。

Comment: Make を使わず直接 `aarch64-elf-gcc` コマンドを実行した際には成功していますか？

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。LINUXマシンを立ち上げ、同じことを行ったところ、素直に通りました。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

`CreateProcess`が193を返したとなると[`ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT)であり、Windows用の有効な実行ファイルではないということになります。
どのように環境を構築されたのか、質問文に記載されていないためわかりませんが、環境を見直してください。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。LINUXマシンを立ち上げ、同じことを行ったところ、素直に通りました。ありがとうございます。